# How can I run a STDEV on specific cells based on mixed groups?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, stdev

I have a spreadsheet that has the value of two groups of participants in an experiment 
(Group 1 and 2). It looks something like this:

```
Group..........Value
1...............5
2...............3
1...............7
1...............5
1...............9
2...............1
1...............0
2...............2
2...............4
2...............5
```

Below I want to create cells that will have the `STDEV` of the different groups.
 E.g. SDGroup1 and SDGroup2

How can I tell Google Sheets to average the values that in the group row have a specific value?

P.S. this is a very simplified snippet, I want to do this for maybe hundreds of rows, and multiple groups, so selecting the cells manually will not do.

Comment: _excel/google sheets/libreoffice calc_ Maybe you'd care to choose just one? _but I'd like to know how to apply other functions such as STDEV._ Right... What other functions did you have in mind? This seems a bit like a laundry list of questions. Why not just start with one spreadsheet format and one function, **OR** let us in on the scret of what you're trying to do and maybe we can really! help you.

Comment: Google sheets STDEV Group#1: `=stdev(filter(B2:B11,A2:A11=1))`; Group#2: `=stdev(filter(B2:B11,A2:A11=2))`

Comment: Did you try googling for this?  Plenty of suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**D1** cell: `=UNIQUE(A2:A)`

**E2** cell: `=STDEV(FILTER(B:B, A:A=D2))`

**E3** cell: `=STDEV(FILTER(B:B, A:A=D3))`

[image: 0]